# can we get the postgres db dump using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pg-dump

Is it possible to have the postgres database dump(pg_dump) using SQLAlchemy? i can get the dump using pg_dump but I am doing all other db operations using SQLALchemy and thus want to know if this dump operation is also opssible using SQLAlchemy. Any suggestion, link would be of great help.

Thanks,
Tara Singh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pg_dump is a system command.so I do not think you could have postgres database dump using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer tinychen. Is there any other ORM which can help doing this ?

Comment: @TaraSingh "pg_dump is a system command.so I do not think you could have postgres database dump using **an ORM**." See @ miniwarks answer for more context.

Answer (score 1):

SqlAlchemy do not manage sort of pg_dump. You probably can mimic it with a buch of queries but it will be painfull.

The more easy way is to use pg_dump itself inside a python script with os.system or subprocess.call

If it's for regular saves also have a look to safekeep project who speak for you to your databases